# Test that function was called inside subscribe

Tags: angular, jasmine

I need to check that my `save()` function was called like shown below. I'm having trouble getting the subscribe to be called so I can check that my `saveSpy` was called.

**some.component.ts**

```
 ionViewWillEnter() {
    this.someService.someSubscription =
      this.someService.someAction.subscribe(() => {
        this.save();
      });
  }
```

**some.component.spec.ts**

```
  it('should set someSubscription on ionViewWillEnter', fakeAsync(() => {
    spyOn(component['someService'], 'someAction').and.callThrough();
    const saveSpy = spyOn(component, 'save');
    component.ionViewWillEnter();
    flush();
    expect(saveSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  }));
```

`TypeError: this.someService.someAction.subscribe is not a function`

Comment: You can use `fakeAsync` together with either `flushMicroTasks()` or `tick()` https://angular.io/api/core/testing/fakeAsync

Comment: @MikeS. `TypeError: this.someService.someAction.subscribe is not a function`

Comment: That error happens because `someAction` is probably not initialized. Make sure `someService` is properly setup before calling `ionViewWillEnter`

Comment: @MikeS. How should I be  setting up `someService`?

Answer (score 0):

because you're subscribing, `save` will be called asynchronously.

Waiting a tick can solve it:

```
import { firstValueFrom, timer } from 'rxjs';

  it('should set someSubscription on ionViewWillEnter', async () => {
    spyOn(component['someService'], 'someAction').and.callThrough();
    const saveSpy = spyOn(component, 'save');
    component.ionViewWillEnter();
    await firstValueFrom(timer(0));
    expect(saveSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```